# How to sum a matrice of matrices

Tags: python-2.7

I have a matrix that each spot in it is another matrix, and I need to print a new matrix which is a form from the sum of each matrix in the same index .

```
 >>sum_matrices([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16]],[[21,22,23],[24,25,26]],[[31,3 2,13],[34,35,36]]]) 

    [[64, 68, 52], [76, 80, 84]]
```

I have this code which adds 2 matrices together.

```
def sum_matrices(mat_lst):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(mat_lst)):
        rows=[]
        for j in range(len(mat_lst)):
            rows.append(add_matrices(mat_lst[i][j]))
        result.append(rows)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
def sum(matrix):
    result = matrix[0][:]
    for i in range(1, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(result)):
            for k in range(len(result[j])):
                result[j][k] += matrix[i][j][k]

    print result
```